# Reduce space between paragraph elements

Tags: html, css

I want to reduce vertical size between `<p>` elements

So I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6r1wb3Lx/) for testing purposes

[image]

As you can see the space between paragraph elements is too much, I try using `line-height: 0`, but it does not make any effect, anyone has an idea why I can not reduce the vertical space between those elements?

HTML:

```
 <div class="container">
     <div class="container__overlay-item">
       <img class="logo" src="https://logo.clearbit.com/facebook.com">
     </div>
     <div class="container__overlay">
       <div>
         <p class="title">Title Test</p>
         <p class="subtitle">This is a title test</p>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

SCSS:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin-top: 5em;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row;
  justify-items: flex-end;
  margin-right: initial;

  &__overlay {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    background-color: #48525D;
    border-radius: 129.5px 0px 0px 129.5px;
    padding: 4% 4%;
    max-width: 1200px;

    &-item {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: left;
    }
  }
}

.logo {
  max-height: 100px;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}


.title {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-family: "Exo 2", sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 4rem;
  text-align: left;
}

.subtitle {
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 1.4;
  font-family: "Exo 2", sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 5rem;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.label {
  font-family: "Exo 2", sans-serif;
  color: #A60A2D;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 3.8rem;
  font-weight: bold;

}
```

Comment: Try line height of `1` on each, and removing the margin, at least on the top one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Chrome's DevTools you can see in your JSFiddle that the `p.title` has `margin-bottom: 16px`. For starters, you can remove that to bring the title and subtitle a bit closer together.

From there, you can make the `line-height` (and `font-size` if necessary) of the `.title` and `.subtitle` smaller and adjust to whatever looks right to you.

The changes could look like this:

```
.title {
    ...,
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 3rem;
    line-height: 3.5rem;   // Or whatever height you want
}

.subtitle {
    ...,
    font-size: 4rem;
    line-height: 4.5rem;   // Or whatever height you want
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try and use developer tools to inspect your elements. If you inspect the first paragraph `.title` you will see that it has a bottom margin which every `<p>` element has by default. You can just add  `.title{margin-bottom:0;}` and the space will be reduced. If you want to use `line-height` you can add something like `.subtite{line-height:0.5;}` and it will be reduced further.